# How can I transform a data frame to run chisquared test on it?

Tags: r, dataframe, chi-squared

```
    word    freq.x  freq.y
1             1       1
2   1D        1       NA
3   5         2       NA
4   a         5       18
5   a0        8       4
6   about     1       NA
7   all       2       2
8   already   1       NA
9   always    2       2
10  and       4       12
11  another   1       NA
```

Let's say I have a data frame that looks like this. It is basically a word frequency table. How can I convert it into a table  so that I can run the chi squared test of independence on it?

```
chisq.test(data.table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chisq.test(data.table$freq.x, data.table$freq.y)` or `chisq.test(as.matrix(data.table[c('freq.x', 'freq.y')]))`